# Call another tab from tab with bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, razor, tabs

I have a set of tabs using bootstrap and in the fist tab i have a link to the second tab, the link works and loads the second tab content but the second tab is not being set to active, why this is happening?

this is my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked col-md-2">
        <li class="active"><a href="#about" data-toggle="tab">¿Qu&eacute; es MeCans&eacute;?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#buy" data-toggle="tab">Comprar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#vipsale" data-toggle="tab">Vender VIP</a></li>
        <li><a href="#devolutions" data-toggle="tab">Devoluciones</a></li>
        <li><a href="#faqs" data-toggle="tab">Preguntas Frecuentes</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content col-md-10">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="about">@Html.Partial("_AboutUs")</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="buy">@Html.Partial("_Buy")</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="vipsale">@Html.Partial("_VipSale")</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="devolutions">@Html.Partial("_Devolutions")</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="faqs">@Html.Partial("_Faq")</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Inside the _Buy partial view i have this link:

```
 <a href="#vipsale" data-toggle="tab">Venta Vip</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not really how `data-toggle` works in this case. The Bootstrap method sets that link active, not the tab associated with the content.

You'll need to use JS:

```
<a href="#" id="vip">Venta Vip</a>

$('#vip').click(function() {
    $('a[href="#vipsale"]').tab('show')
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/f34x8 (link in last tab)